# Bluebird promise generators with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

**How do I make bluebird automatically add `.nodeify`/`.asCallback` to a generated promise?**

In bluebird, any promise instance can be attached to a node callback mechanism:

`Promise.resolve('foo').asCallback(callback);`

However, sometimes one may need to define not the promise itself, but a method that, when called, returns a new promise each time, like these:

```
// create a new random number promise each time
Promise.method((foo, callback) => Math.random());

// create a new random number promise each time using a generator
Promise.coroutine(function *(foo, callback) {
    return Math.random();
});
```

In this scenario, if I wanted to attach a callback handler to the promise, I'd have to do so "artificially" at the end, using an improvised method like this:

```
// create a new random number promise each time using a generator
Promise.coroutine(function *(foo, callback) {
    // do some other stuff
    return Promise.resolve(Math.random()).asCallback(callback);
});
```

However, realistically, my promise is more complex, and there are a bunch of things that could happen in between, such as uncaught errors getting thrown. If no callback handler is attached to the promise at that time, the error will only be able to get caught if the promise is processed using `.catch`, and `callback` will never get called.

So, how do I make a promise generator attach a callback handler to each generated promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't attach the callback inside the generator function, you attach it where the coroutine is called:

```
const myPromiseFunction = Promise.coroutine(function* (foo) {
    // do some other stuff
    return Math.random();
});
const myCallbackFunction = (foo, callback) => {
    myPromiseFunction(foo).asCallback(callback);
};
// or compatible with both promise and callback usage:
const myFunction = (foo, callback) => {
    return myPromiseFunction(foo).asCallback(callback);
};
```

That means creating two separate functions, but you shouldn't need to do this that often anyway. If you insist on doing it inline, you can also use `Promise.try` instead of `Promise.method` and `Promise.spawn` (deprecated!) instead of `Promise.coroutine`, which immediately call the function.

Comment: Hi @bergi, thanks for your response! Unfortunately, in my scenario, I'm trying to write a function for an SDK that is used by third parties. Some of the third parties may be using it with promises, and others with callbacks. With that solution, those third parties would have to know to add `.nodeify` or `.asCallback` themselves. While possible, it would be much preferable if the method was automatically compatible with both.

Comment: @arik Personally I would just force them to use promises, that makes it easier for everyone :-) But `asCallback` returns the promise, so you can just `return` that and have a function that is compatible with both.

Comment: Preach! And I have solved it using your second suggestion:
```
function(foo, callback) {
  return Promise.coroutine(function *(){
    // do stuff here
  })()
  .asCallback(callback);
}
```

Comment: @arik That's missing an invocation of the coroutine - either `return Promise.coroutine(…)().asCallback(…);` or `return Promise.spawn(…).asCallback(…);` - but neither is as efficient as the separate declaration.

Comment: You're right, but no worries, I only forgot the invocation in the comment. It works like a charm in the actual code :)